# Cursor do mouse - JavaScript e CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

O `cursor: pointer` é uma propriedade CSS que define o cursor do mouse como um "ponteiro" sobre determinado elemento.

Até aqui tudo tranquilo, vale ressaltar que no JavaScript eu também posso adicionar um cursor do mouse sobre determinado evento.

```js
document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('mouseover',() => {
  document.querySelector('.element').style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
```

```html
<p class="element">Just an example</p>
```

Porém, apesar de entender a ideia fico com algumas dúvidas:

- A propriedade `cursor: pointer` não simula um comportamento para
  determinada situação? Se sim, por que ela é definida via CSS e não
  somente por JavaScript?
- O que o JavaScript realmente faz ao adicionar esse cursor? Adiciona
  um estilo no elemento com CSS?
- Em relação a outras propriedades CSS adicionadas sobre um elemento, ele 
  "toma" a mesma atitude que a do cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A propriedade `cursor:pointer` não simula um comportamento para determinada situação? Se sim, por que ela é definida via CSS e não somente por JavaScript?**

O JS não simula o comportamento do elemento, ele simula o comportamento do cursor do mouse. Repare que o HTML tem vários elementos que por convenção se utilizam do cursor do mouse para dar um *feedback* visual para o usuário. Por exemplo a tag `<a>` usa o `cursor:pointer` e a tag `<input>` usa o `cursor:text`. Colocar um `cursor:text` em uma `<div>` não vai mudar o comportamento da `<div>` apenas vai confundir o usuário, pois ele pode entender que é possível digitar um texto na `div`...

Exitem uma série de tipos de cursor. A própria MicroSoft já abordou isso nesse artigo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/uxguide/inter-mouse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Objetos de interface de usuário (UI) bem projetados são considerados
>   como ***affordance***, que são propriedades visuais e comportamentais
>   de um objeto que sugere como ele é usado. O ponteiro funciona como um
>   proxy para a mão, permitindo que os usuários interajam com objetos de
>   tela de maneira muito parecida com objetos físicos.

Isso quer dizer que o cursor é uma extensão da mão do usuário, e ele leva em consideração o tipo do ponteiro para saber a forma que ele vai interagir com o elemento, se é clicando, arrastando, digitando, etc...

Outro ponto é com relação a acessibilidade. As tags `<button>`, `<label>` e `<input>` por exemplo são interpretadas de uma forma pelos leitores de tela, e o "tipo" de cursor pouco vai importar para eles. O principal nesse caso é se preocupar com a semântica do código, o uso correto dos atributos  `roles` e dos `aria` vc pode ler sobre eles aqui: https://tableless.com.br/wai-aria-estendendo-o-significado-das-interacoes/

**Observação:** Clicar com o botão direito do mouse, clicar duas vezes (double click) e clicar com os modificadores de tecla `Shift` ou `Ctrl` são três interações do mouse que não são intuitivas , porque não têm contrapartes no mundo real.

---

**O que o JavaScript realmente faz ao adicionar esse cursor? Adiciona um estilo no elemento com CSS?**

Sim ele adiciona o estilo na hora, porém trocar cursor não é fazer um `:hover`. Repare que seu código troca o cursor colocando um estilo `cursor:pointer` diretamente na tag (tipo um `style inline`), mas quando vc tira o cursor de cima do elemento ele continua com o `cursor:pointer` setado na tag. O que o seu script faz não é propriamente um `:hover` e um leitor de tela não entenderia que foi feito um `:hover` e não "veria" que o cursou foi alterado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `:hover` sempre vai existir, assim que o DOM e CSSOM for construído todos os elementos já terão seu estilo de `:hover` declarado pelo CSS, já com o JS vc só vai aplicar o estilo quando o evento acontecer no elemento, algo que pode até depender do hardware ou da conexão do usuário para ter uma boa performance. Como vc viu na imagem o estilo do cursor não existe ainda até que o usuário interaja com o elemento. Já com CSS o estilo já estará "programado", é algo como o "`will change`", onde o browser já sabe que aquele elemento vai sofrem uma interação ou animação. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

---

**Em relação a outras propriedades CSS adicionadas sobre um elemento, ele "toma" a mesma atitude que a do cursor?**

Acredito que sim, mas não sei dizer exatamente como o browser e os leitores de tela entendem o JS, pois na maioria dos casos são eventos que só são disparados quando o usuário faz alguma interação. Alguns dos eventos não executam quando a página carrega, mas só quando tem alguma ação por parte do usuário. ***O que eu posso dizer é que o tipo do cursor não muda o tipo do elemento.***

*Para leitura:*

- https://uxdesign.cc/missing-the-pointer-1dfc5cd60c8c
- https://medium.com/simple-human/buttons-shouldnt-have-a-hand-cursor-b11e99ca374b

Comment: Simplesmente sensacional! Tudo o que precisava saber para entender melhor!

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz que bom que te deu uma luz. Não deixe der ler os links que citei, nem que seja uma leitura dinâmica rss

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes.

> A propriedade `cursor: pointer` não simula um comportamento para
>   determinada situação? Se sim, por que ela é definida via `CSS` e não
>   somente por JavaScript?

A propriedade `cursor` do elemento simplesmente altera a forma como o cursor do mouse é visualizado ao ser colocado acima do elemento em questão, por isso é definido em `CSS` que é responsável por definir o estilo dos elementos definidos em `HTML` existem pseudo-classes em `CSS` que nos fornecem "ganchos" para determinar a ocorrência de determinado evento no elemento por exemplo:

```css
#dv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#dv:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="dv"></div>
```

Como pode ver no exemplo acima quando o mouse está sobre o elemento é aplicado sobre o mesmo as propriedades definidos para o evento em questão, isso ocorre porque determinado condição(no caso, que o mouse esteja sobre o elemento) foi cumprida. O problema é que hávera casos em que você irá querer criar suas próprias condições dependentes de valores dinâmicos por exemplo, um script que recebe as notas de um determinado aluno e calcula sua média, e dependendo do resultado,  o mesmo veja um botão de redirecionamento isso irá depender de valores externos, aí entra o `Javascript`.

> O que o JavaScript realmente faz ao adicionar esse cursor? Adiciona um
>   estilo no elemento com CSS?

Faz exatamente o mesmo que o `CSS` exceto que com `Javascript` é possível definir uma determinada lógica antes de aplicar esse estilo no elemento tudo de forma dinâmica.

> Em relação a outras propriedades CSS adicionadas sobre um elemento,
>   ele "toma" a mesma atitude que a do cursor?

Não entendi muito bem essa pergunta, mas se está relacianada ao fato de se a propriedades `CSS` adicionada de forma dinâmica atuará de forma semelhante ao caso do cursor, a resposta é sim. Como disse anteriormente `Javascript` sisplesmente no provê a capacidade de dinamicamente aplicar essa propriedade sob determinada condição, se a mesma puder ser implementada com `CSS`utlizando-se de `pseudo-classes` acredito que seja a abordagem a ser seguida.

Comment: Na verdade o javascript está alterando o `style` para que ele faça a mesma declaração do `cursor: pointer` no CSS?

Comment: Exatamente isso se chama `DOM` e permite o `Javascript` manipular os elementos definidos no documento, excluí-los e até mesmo inserir novos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Ajudou bastante a entender!